# IGCSE/GCSE mathematics worksheet and resources

Tags: online-resources

I take mathematics for Cambdridge IGCSE students, Syllabus code 0580, http://www.cie.org.uk/docs/dynamic/41073.pdf ,  Please i want to know about resources available to revise the math topics,  and if there are any websites that provides the  worksheets and  lesson plans IGCSE or GCSE syllabus.

Thanks,
Arif

Comment: Arif, you accidentally created a duplicate account. I have merged it into your current account. If you register your account, it should help avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: Previous papers are available at http://www.xtremepapers.com/papers/CIE/

Answer (score -2):

Try this link below it has some topics and more everyday.
https://nerdherdcorner.com/gcse-revision/maths-revision/